# Access a socket that has been passed to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, casyncsocket, mfc-networking

I am new to MFC's `CWinThread` and `CAsyncSocket`, and trying to learn them myself with dialog based application. 

**Here is what I want to do:** *make a server/multi-client model*: when the number clients connect to server, the server will make threads according to the number of clients and passes the socket connecting to the thread. I have refereed this article to do the passing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175668 .


I have successfully make thread on every connection, but...

**My question is:** Can I from the main windows(GUI) re-access all sockets that have been passed to threads to **send**(broadcast) data to all the clients?


This is how I do the passing:

On server side:

```
void CMyServerDlg::OnAccept(){
CConnectSoc temp_soc;
m_Listener.Accept(temp_soc);
CSocketThread *pThr = (CSocketThread*)AfxBeginThread(
                                    RUNTIME_CLASS(CSocketThread),
                                    THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                                    0,
                                    CREATE_SUSPENDED);
pThr->threadHandleSocket = temp_soc.Detach();
pThr->ResumeThread();
}
```

Note: `m_Listener` is the object of the class that derived from `CAsyncSocket` and `CSocketThread` is derived from `CWinThread`. 

Inside the thread header, I added 2 lines:

```
Public:
CConnectSoc threadSocket;
SOCKET threadHandleSocket;
```

Inside the thread class .cpp:

```
BOOL CSocketThread::InitInstance(){

     threadSocket.Attach(threadHandleSocket);
     return TRUE;
}
```

Can someone tell me what to do next to send data to those socket?

Comment: Post message to the thread using [PostThreadMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To post the messages from threads to the main GUI use the normal `PostMessage()`

Comment: @cha Thank you for your comment, I did a research and `PostThreadMessage()` require m_hthreadID. So I guess we need to `PostMessage()` from the thread first to get that ID. And store them in an array somewhere for the the main GUI can do a loop of `PostThreadMessage()`? is that what I need to do?

Comment: `AfxBeginThread` returns a pointer to a `CWinThread` object, which has a member function `PostThreadMessage`. You just have to store the pointer returned by `AfxBeginThread`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have found the way to do this. I will post my own answer for this in a short time. Thank you for all your comments.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I finally think I can answer my own question, thanks for your help; but please fix me, if there is a better solution or mine is not a good practice.


**MY SOLUTION:**

The key word here is `PostMessage()` and `PostThreadMessage()`. We must make the communication between the GUI and the Threads. However, the problem is the thread cannot call `PostMessage()` which is a member function of `CWnd` to send message to the GUI (I have no idea why not). So I need a pointer in the thread class to point to the CWnd from the GUI:


**In header of the thread class:**

```
public:
   CWnd *wParrent;
```

Then at the stage of creating thread, I just have to add 1 line:

```
void CMyServerDlg::OnAccept(){
   CConnectSoc temp_soc;
   m_Listener.Accept(temp_soc);
   CSocketThread *pThr = (CSocketThread*)AfxBeginThread(
                                RUNTIME_CLASS(CSocketThread),
                                THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                                0,
                                CREATE_SUSPENDED);
   pThr->wParrent = this;  //<== this line
   pThr->threadHandleSocket = temp_soc.Detach();
   pThr->ResumeThread();
}
```

By doing this, I can now post message from the thread to give the GUI my thread's ID. 

**In the thread .cpp:**

```
BOOL CSocketThread::InitInstance(){
   threadSocket.Attach(threadHandleSocket);
   wParrent->PostMessage(THREAD_STARTED, 0, (LPARAM)m_nThreadID);
   return TRUE;
}
```

Then at GUI: we handle message `THREAD_STARTED` with a function to store `m_nThreadID` for future use:

**Somewhere in Dlg header:**

```
CDWordArray m_threadIDs;
```

**Dlg .cpp**

```
LRESULT CMyServer3Dlg::OnThreadStart(WPARAM, LPARAM lParam){
   DWORD ThreadID = (DWORD)lParam;
   m_threadIDs.Add(ThreadID);
   return 0;
}
```

When sending data to all clients, use `PostThreadMessage()` in a loop through `m_ThreadIDs`:

```
for (int i =0; i<m_threadIDs.GetCount(); ++i){
   PostThreadMessage(m_threadIDs[i],SEND_DATA,(WPARAM)bufferSize,(LPARAM)socketBuffer);
}
```

Handle `SEND_DATA` message in the thread with a function to do the sending:

**In thread .cpp:**

```
void CSocketThread::SendDataFunc(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
   ASSERT(threadSocket != NULL);
   if(threadSocket == NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       char *socketBuffer = (char*)lParam;
       int bufferSize = (int)wParam;
       send(threadSocket, socketBuffer, bufferSize, 0);
   }
```

That's what I have done, and no problem so far....